# gray color on logic function with NMOS in Proteus

Tags: proteus, nmos

I'm trying to design this function:

```
(A.B) + (C.D)
```

every things work fine but there is one weird issue that both branch (A.B) and (C.D) must be 1 or 0 at same time otherwise gray color appears and output comes unknown (as shown in screenshot below) what should i do to fix this?

[image: proteus design]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research i figure out finally that NMOS have impedance problem in design so voltages change when you using them in series mode. that's one of the reason we using CMOS